# How do I change where images are stored with appengine devserver

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

For local development with appengine, I need to change where uploaded images are stored with the GCS service so that they are persisted across builds. Right now, a new build wipes out the target directory along with the images in the appengine-generated directory.

I had the same problem with the datastore but was able to fix this by setting a property to use a datastore located in my repo outside of the target directory.

```
-Ddatastore.backing_store=../../local_db.bin
```

Is there a comparable property for the images/files saved using the GCS service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @alex pointed out, there is a parameter to define where all local files are stored for python and it exists for java too.

For java the parameter is `--generated_dir=<path>` which is a server param not a JVM option.

Also note that this overwrites the usage of `-Ddatastore.backing_store=<local_db.bin>`.

There documentation on this feature here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

With the Python local server, `--storage_path=...` determines where everything is stored ("Datastore, Blobstore files, Google Cloud Storage Files, logs, etc", to quote the docs) unless explicitly overridden. It doesn't appear that the possible values listed for Java at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/constant-values encompass a similarly all-inclusive path, however.

Comment: This is a good time to mention, OP, that if you'd like to make a feature request, you can lodge it in the [Cloud Platform Public Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/list).